# removeClass onde o link interno seja um espacífico

Tags: jquery

Tenho o seguinte HTML:

```
<div class="segura-li">
    <li class="classe-li">
       <a href="link1">texto</a>
    </li>
    <li class="classe-li">
       <a href="link2">texto</a>
    </li>
    <li class="classe-li">
       <a href="link3">texto</a>
    </li>
</div>
```

Como remover APENAS o elemtno `li` que dentro do `a` tenha a URL `link2`?

Se eu fizer isso removo todos:

```
$('.segura-li').removeClass('.classe-li');
```

Comment: Mas quer remover o elemento `<li>` ou a classe dele?

Comment: O elemento, editei a minha pergunta

Comment: Se for pra remover o elemento, pode ser `$('.segura-li [href="link2"]').closest("li").remove()`

Comment: E por que usou `removeClass`?

Comment: Pode ser também apenas: `$('[href="link2"]').closest("li").remove()` se só houver esse link na página... são várias as possibilidades.... pode ser tb `$(".segura-li .classe-li:eq(1)").closest("li").remove()`... Só que pergunta contradiz o que vc acabou de comentar: _"O elemento, editei a minha pergunta"_.

Comment: Falta só vc responder o que está querendo fazer. O título da pergunta diz uma coisa e o texto diz outra.